# Glycemic Index and two-hour blood glucose response curve (AUC)? Where are the AUC charts?

Tags: human-biology, nutrition, glucose

I understand the "Glycemic Index" (GI) of foods is calculated using the area under a 2-hour glucose/blood response curve (AUC) after a 24 hour fast and consuming carbohydrates. Therefore a higher GI indicates there is more glucose available in the blood stream during this 2 hours.

It seems the GI is a general indicator and glucose/blood levels over 2 hours and has little information on when the spike of carbohydrate to glucose conversion occurs or when carbohydrates are first converted to glucose. Is this a true statement?

I searched for the AUC charts online but found little information. I suspect the AUC charts would show when the glucose/blood levels first increase and how they are effected over time. Does anyone know where to find these charts for foods?

Also, is the correct forum to be asking this in? Unsure if Beta Medical Sciences StackExchance is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search something like:

https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&q=glycemic+index+AUC+glucose

and your results will include papers that calculate glycemic index for some food based on glucose measurements. For example this one:

*Robert, S. D., Ismail, A. A. S., Winn, T., & Wolever, T. (2008). Glycemic index of common Malaysian fruits. Asia Pacific Journal of Clinical Nutrition, 17(1).*

has this figure:

[image: Plasma glucose responses]

You can expect that the conversion of carbohydrates to glucose begins immediately after eating, so it's mostly the *rate* that varies by food, producing different curves.

Comment: This paper is available from https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18364324/

Comment: I added another question on performing the GI calculation using integral calculus here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/110854/calculating-the-glycemic-index-using-an-auc-glucose-blood-curve